# C# How to prevent ListBox to select first item when you unselect the last one

Tags: c#, listbox, selection

C# How to prevent ListBox in MultiSimple selection mode to select first item automatically, when you unselect the last one selected item in the box - it happens only if listbox represented by my own class objects, and everything is ok when it represented by string objects. Thnx!

Comment: As i understand problem fires when i use deserialization of List<MyClass> by binaryFormatter. When i switchOff this loading of list at startup everithing is OK. The code of Reading is: 

 `public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)

        {

            using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);

            }
        }`

Comment: can you use listBoxName.ClearSelected() ?

Comment: I can, but my program must remember selected items after reordering list, and the order of selected and unselected items is shift and broke after reordering, and first item continuously selects after deselecting any other last selected item. And that is not happened when I comment code with ReadingFromBinaryFile, and nothing else. It's a strange thing, and I don't understand why happen so.

Comment: So i make an ugly patch to resolve it - everytime when last item deselected i make ClearSelected as you say. But i still want to understand what is cause of this bug when after assigning as dataSource preloaded list of class, the first item of list selected everytime. And if list of tags is empty and uploaded by printing words in run time, the problem is not firedup. Anyway thank you. PS VS2008 with Net.3.5

Comment: Sorry, I was typing my answer before I saw your comment, not sure if my answer will, help, but good luck

Answer (score 1):

It seems like keeping track of the order of the list is the most important part.  I would suggest maybe making an array of a struct.  You can make this struct contain whatever you want for example:

```
struct itemList
{
    public string itemName;
    public int itemIndex;
    //include whatever other variables that you need included in here.

}
```

Also, make sure you place your struct before the namespace.  Then, making the array of the struct would look like this:

```
itemList[] items1 = new itemList[listBoxName.SelectedItems.Count];
```

All you would have to do then is to add the items to the array before you reorder the listBox

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxName.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
   {
        items1[i].itemName = listBoxName.SelectedItems[i].ToString();
        items1[i].itemIndex = listBoxName.SelectedIndices[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, but i already use some like this. I don't understand why first item of listBox selected everytime i assign preloaded list as DataSource. I resolve this problem, by making another one temporal List of my object class, which items readed from binary file, and then push them one by one to my original List in foreach cycle by listOfObjects.Add(object) method. I know that every time after code `ListOfTags.DataSource = null;
            ListOfTags.DataSource = tags;
            ListOfTags.DisplayMember = "Name";`  if my tags (it is a List) are preloaded even in code (for example if i write code `List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> {new Tag("1"),new Tag("2"), new Tag("3")};` , this takes situation when first item of listbox selected, and starts selects everytime after that when i try do deselect last selected item in listBox.